# SQL convert string(date or text) to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database which has a column called `stringNextDue` that contains data like dates (UK format) and text (e.g "overdue", "completed")

I am trying to create a view that shows courses that are due within a month from now:

```
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, mt.stringNextDue , 103) < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())
```

This throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Which is probably due to the fact that `stringNextDue` may contain actual strings of text.

I tried using

```
WHERE 
    ISDATE(mt.NextDateString) = 1 
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, mt.stringNextDue , 103) < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())
```

But `ISDATE` only accepts US date formats therefore ignoring a lot of actual dates as strings

Tried `set dateformat 'dmy'`, which fixed the `IsDate` issue, but it cannot be used in views.

Any suggestions?

Server update is not an option

Comment: Lots of product specific SQL there. Tag the dbms product you're using!

Comment: Any hope you could upgrade to SQL Server **2012**? It has excellent functions like `TRY_CONVERT` etc. that would allow you to handle this very nicely

Comment: What is the EU date format?  I wasn't aware that there was a standard.    You might be interested in this Wikipedia article:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Date_and_time_representation_by_country.  (You'll note that some countries such as Poland and Sweden have adopted the ISO 8601 standard.)

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use the new `TRY_CONVERT` you might use a function like this:

Attention: This will not catch a wrong date like 31.06.2016, you'd have to modify the `BETWEEN 1 AND 31` if you need this...

Attention2: If your text might include characters forbidden in xml you should replace `<` with `&lt;`, `>` with `&gt;` and `&` with `&amp;` ...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestDate(@TestString VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @x XML=CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@TestString,'.','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)

    DECLARE @p1 VARCHAR(10) = @x.value('x[1]','varchar(10)');
    DECLARE @p2 VARCHAR(10) = @x.value('x[2]','varchar(10)');
    DECLARE @p3 VARCHAR(10) = @x.value('x[3]','varchar(10)');

    IF    LEN(@p1)=2 AND ISNUMERIC(@p1)=1 AND CAST(@p1 AS INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 31
      AND LEN(@p2)=2 AND ISNUMERIC(@p2)=1 AND CAST(@p2 AS INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 12
      AND LEN(@p3)=4 AND ISNUMERIC(@p3)=1 AND CAST(@p3 AS INT) BETWEEN 1900 AND 2100

    RETURN CONVERT(DATETIME, @TestString , 103);

    RETURN NULL;
END
GO

SELECT
  dbo.TestDate('overdue') AS SureNoDate
 ,dbo.TestDate('01.04.2016') AS EuropeanDate
 ,dbo.TestDate('2016.04.01') AS WrongFormat
 ,dbo.TestDate('01.13.2016') AS BadDate;
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestDate;
```

The result

```
SureNoDate  EuropeanDate    WrongFormat BadDate
NULL        2016-04-01      NULL        NULL
```

You might pass back a valid date (`RETURN GETDATE()` ?) instead of `RETURN NULL` for your comparisson outside. This depends on your needs...

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to replace WHERE clause using this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  -- sample data
  (values('2015-01-01'),('01-01-2015'), ('x-x-x-x')) mt(NextDateString)
-- Replace WHERE statement with the following
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    RIGHT('0000'+PARSENAME(REPLACE(mt.NextDateString, '-', '.'), 1),4) yyy,
    RIGHT('0000'+PARSENAME(REPLACE(mt.NextDateString, '-', '.'), 2),4) mmm,
    RIGHT('0000'+PARSENAME(REPLACE(mt.NextDateString, '-', '.'), 3),4) ddd
) x
WHERE 
  x.yyy BETWEEN '1950' AND '2050'
  AND x.mmm BETWEEN '0001' AND '0012'
  AND x.ddd BETWEEN '0001' AND '0031'
  AND  ISDATE(mt.NextDateString) = 1
  AND x.yyy+x.mmm+x.ddd < CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()), 112)
```

Result:

```
NextDateString  yyy   mmm   ddd
01-01-2015      2015  0001  0001
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestions,

I fixed it by setting language to British on user settings

```
EXEC sp_defaultlanguage 'username', 'british'
```

Comment: This might be a dangerous fix with various side effects ... I would not walk this path ...