# Parsing wrong date format in SQL server from XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, date, datetime

I have a XML data in which the Date format is changes sometime it comes as 
**yyyy-dd-MM(T)HH:mm:ss** and some time it came as **yyyy-MM-dd(T)HH:mm:ss**.

While parsing the XML, i am unsure how to handle this case as my SQL Server default language is **Us_english**.

If I uses BEGIN TRY AND CATCH statement in SQL SERVER and error occurs while parsing the data the Execution of the PROC stops.

**Code sample**

```
BEGIN TRY
Select Cast(Replace(C.H.value('SameDateColumn[1]','nvarchar(20)'),'T',' ')   as Datetime) as 'DateHistory'
from @XMLIN.nodes('//HeaderT') C(H);
set language Us_english
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
set language british
END CATCH
```

Is there any way, so if the exception occurs I can set the default language to **british** and execute the code after the END CATCH statement in SQL SERVER.

I have also tried to use ISDATE() method but every time it gives me 1 as the output regardless of the **us_english** format or **british**.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have no way to ensure what date format  the current xml node contains you are out of luck, since these formats are indistinguishable for any date between the 1ts and 12th of each month.

Comment: How is this XML generated? Is this under your control? If this is done properly differing formats should never occur... Is the `(T)` in your date really in paranthesis? Especially the `yyyy-dd-MMT...` is not the way XML would store a date. What happens if you put 'datetime' as target type into the `.value()` function? You might read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36310961/5089204

Comment: XML is being generated by third party and based on the location of the Third party server the XML date format changes.
also the **(T)** is to display purpose, XML returning the Date as           **2016-04-22T09:45:00**. 
also going through the link, i guess it will help me if I use that function or create new function to handle the wrong date format.

Comment: @ShashankAwasthy Next time you answer a comment, please add a `@Shnugo` to your answer. Without this, there's no alert. I found your answer by chance...  I think you've got something wrong, but this is to much for a comment. Will place an answer soon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in my comment, I think there is kind of misunderstanding...

I think, that the differing formats *don't come from bad data in the XML* but they are a result of your attempts to convert the content in different systems...

You read the date like this:

```
Select Cast(Replace(C.H.value('SameDateColumn[1]','nvarchar(20)'),'T',' ')   as Datetime) as 'DateHistory'
from @XMLIN.nodes('//HeaderT') C(H);
```

That means: You read the date from *within* the XML as text (`nvarchar(20)`. Now you replace the "T" and then you cast this string to a `DateTime`. This last step is depending on your system's culture and the language in use. It is even depending from the user's login!.

If everything goes the correct way, any date *within* an XML should be ISO8601 and look like this:

```
2016-04-21T15:21:00
```

Try to read the date like this:

```
Select C.H.value('SameDateColumn[1]','datetime') as 'DateHistory'
from @XMLIN.nodes('//HeaderT') C(H);
```

If the XML was created correctly, this should work and no conversion is needed at all.

Comment: @Shungo, fixed my problem by implementing the solution, I will be careful in future while parsing the XML file to read it correctly with the same data type as of the column data type.

Comment: @ShashankAwasthy, Glad to read this! Yes, that is one of the biggest advantages of XML as datatype: You can store and read your data string based without bothering about conversions or encodings. This is all done implicitly...